Adding assumed ECS TaskRole to KMS Key Policy
I have an ECS task with execute-command enabled and with encrypted access and logging. When I try to connect to the container, I get error:
AccessDeniedException: User: arn:aws:sts::444444444444444:assumed-role/EcsTaskRole-b2c7a1c/16ea518d28a14c7f9593044d7db7b0c4 is not authorized to perform: kms:Decrypt on resource...
But because I cannot add any wildcard in KMS Key policy (I get InvalidArnException), I cannot allow arn:aws:sts::444444444444444:assumed-role/EcsTaskRole-b2c7a1c/* there. How can I fix it, though?

it'd help if you can add both policies

Typically, you would add the root account ARN in the KMS  policy, which has the somewhat confusing and non-obvious effect of enabling IAM roles to control access to the KMS key. Then you would simply add the kms:Decrypt permission to the IAM role you are assigning to the ECS task. As stated above, it would really help if you included both policies in your question.

So if I allow everyone in the Key policy, it doesn't give them the permission to use the key, it just allows them to be allowed in the role policy? That would solve it, then. Thanks

No you don't allow "everyone" ("*") you allow the Root user of your AWS account. Then that allows IAM roles inside your account to control access. It's a very specific thing you have to do in the KMS policy, and it's not obvious at all how it works. It is documented here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/key-policy-default.html#key-policy-default-allow-root-enable-iam
